# What tools can I use to a text overlay to a video?

Tags: video-editor, mp4

I have an MP4 that I uploaded from my Android to my Ubuntu workstation for editing. What tools can I use on Ubuntu to fade in and out professional-looking text?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use Openshot or Kdenlive to achieve this effect.

**Click here to install Openshot:**
[image: Install via the software center]

> [image: Openshot Screen Shot]
>   ***Openshot***

To add text to your video, go to

- **Title→New Title**

or

- **Title→New Animated Title**

in the menu. You can add effects and transitions to Titles as you would to any other component of the video.

---

**Click here to install Kdenlive:***
[image: Install via the software center]

> [image: Kdenlive Screenshot]
>   ***Kdenlive***

You can add a title clip (text) to your video by going to:

- **Project→Add Title Clip**

Or you can do it by right clicking on the project tree and clicking **"Add Title Clip"**.

> [image: Screenshot of clip window with context menu]

As with Openshot, you can add effects and transitions to Title Clips.

---

**Kdenlive will pull in some KDE dependencies.*

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `gstreamer` directly to do this.

Here's an example:

```
gst-launch filesrc location="<Filepath>" ! textoverlay text="Title : Hello" valign=top halign=left ! xvimagesink
```

There are also lot of other configurable options that you can use.

Hope this helps.