# How do I automate simple video edits?

Tags: command-line, video-editor

I have a set of video clips, that all need the same title/end image added, then cross-faded into (and at the end, out of) the video.

I figure there's a way to automate this with `ffmpeg` or `avconv`, I just don't know where to look.

Or perhaps it's not that simple, but a cinelerra/open shot/pitivi project file could be 'templatized' - and the render automated.

Comment: Found this, but still interested in other solutions: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcUid3OP_4OWC-GJ6KfHK7dIK_yRKKn0e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `melt` and instead of giving it a video file use an image file that you either join to the video at the begining or end (remember to give it an `out=` time in frames to define the time length of the image) or that you blend with a filter.

A lot of examples and uses of other commands too:

- [Command-line video editing in Linux (cut, join and preview)](https://superuser.com/questions/358082/command-line-video-editing-in-linux-cut-join-and-preview)

> To utilize images (say, .png) in a video edit composition:
>
> ```
> melt \
> video.avi in=30 out=79 \
> test.png in=0 out=15 \
> video.avi in=30 out=79 \
> -blank 15
> ```
>
> Note that for test.png, in= parameter doesn't need to be 0 - however,
>   the image will be displayed for out-in time; in this case, it would be
>   easiest to simply leave the in=0 parameter out altogether.

The [youtube playlist](http://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcUid3OP_4OWC-GJ6KfHK7dIK_yRKKn0e) that you mention in your comment is really good and simple to understand. It gives good examples of the commands and also of how to write simple scripts in Bash to iterate the use of filters and mixes over multiple files. Worth watching!

Here it explains how to [add to your video text using gstreamer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179109/what-tools-can-i-use-to-a-text-overlay-to-a-video/179111#179111):

> `gst-launch filesrc location="<Filepath>" ! textoverlay text="Title : Hello" valign=top halign=left ! xvimagesink`